# Apply Bitmask to BufferedImage

Tags: java, performance, opengl, bufferedimage, bitmask

I'm developing a Worms-like game (with destructible terrain and everything) in Java.

All did fine until i tried to update the terrain image using a bitmask.

Let me explain the process in detail :

1. Whenever a projectile collision occurs i draw a black circle into my
   terrain mask (which has black for transparent and white for opaque pixels).

   ```
   public void drawExplosion(Vector2 position,BufferedImage explosionImage){
       Graphics2D gMask = (Graphics2D) terrainMask.getGraphics();
       gMask.drawImage(explosionImage,(int) position.x, (int) position.y, null);
       gMask.dispose();
   }
   ```
2. After the black circle was drawn into my terrainMask `BufferedImage` whose type is
   `BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED`, i update my visible terrain `BufferedImage` by setting
   every pixel to 0 if the terrainMask's pixel is black at the same position.

   ```
   public void mapUpdate(){
    for(int x = 0 ; x < terrainMask.getWidth(); x++){
     for(int y = 0 ; y < terrainMask.getHeight(); y++){
      if(terrainMask.getRGB(x, y) == -16777216){
       terrain.setRGB(x, y, 0);
      }
     }
    }
   }
   ```

After these steps the terrain `BufferedImage` is updated and every looks fine, showing the
explosion hole in the terrain.

Here comes my problem :

Whenever I call `mapUpdate()` the Game stops for 300-500 ms checking 2400*600 pixels and setting transparent pixels in the terrain if a check returns true.

Without `setRGB()` the lag does not occur. So my Question is how can I apply a bitmask to
a `BufferedImage` more efficiently.

Important : All `BufferedImages` are converted to compatible ones using
             `GraphicsConfiguration.createCompatibleImage()` method.

When I call `getData()` on the `BufferedImage` to get the pixel array, the fps drops to
~23 fps making the game unplayable, so this is not an option here.

I also set`System.setProperty("sun.java2d.opengl","True");`

to enabled OpenGL Pipeline. Another weird thing is whenever i don't set the openGL property my Game reaches more than 700 fps (with openGL enabled 140 - 250 fps) and my laptop freezes completely. My game loop is the same as described here : http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/ (Constant Game Speed independent of Variable FPS , the last one).

Comment: Hate to say it, but you're doing it wrong. If you want to do this efficiently in OpenGL, you should be using shaders and buffer objects rather than reading data back and sending new data to GL using the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer ! Do you have any usefull tutorials for using shaders and buffer objects ? Although I set the opengl property I don't really understand what it does and how to use it efficiently except for making images compatible. If you are talking about JOGL : Unfortunately I am not allowed to use third-party libraries.

Comment: I would not worry about this then. It will take a lot of effort to learn to use GLSL, etc. If you are trying to meet some sort of deadline / software requirements that forbid the use of a third-party library, then for performance you should stick to the original non-GL code path you had. GL can actually hurt your performance if you use it wrong, and this is one example of that.

Comment: Except for the setProperty() and createCompatibleImage() i haven't done anything else. When I comment it out my CPU goes all way up to 100% and my system freezes. Do you know of any possible mistakes I could have made ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way you can do this in Java (i.e. no OpenGL) that I know of, would be to:

a) Change your mask (`terrainMask`) image's colors to white and transparent (instead of white and black). Just changing the color table (`IndexColorModel`) will do, I guess.

b) Replace the double `getRGB/setRGB` loop with painting the mask over the terrain, using the proper alpha composite rule. Both `setRGB` and `getRGB` are potentially slow operations, due to lookups, color conversion and possible data type conversion (all depending on your images), so they should generally be avoided in performance critical code. The updated code could look something like the following:

```
public void mapUpdate() {
    Graphics2D g = terrain.createGraphics();
    try {
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.DstIn); // Porter-Duff "destination-in" rule
        g.drawImage(terrainMask); // Clear out transparent parts from terrainMask
    }
    finally {
         g.dispose();
    }
}
```

Doing it this way should also keep your images managed (i.e. no fps drop).

For more information on [`AlphaComposite`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html), see [Compositing Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html) from the Java2D Advanced Topics tutorial.

PS: Another optimization you could do, is to only update the part of `terrain` that are covered by the explosion (i.e. the rectangle covered by `position.x, position.y, explosionImage.getWidth(), explosionImage.getHeight()`). No need to update the pixels you know isn't covered...

Comment: AMAZING ! But is there another rule to make it erase the black parts of the source image (1bpp Bitmap B/W) not the transparent ones ? With your approach I would have to make one version to draw to my terrainMask (black = space to delete, alpha = nothing) and one version (black = nothing, alpha = space to delete) to draw to my terrain. Sorry for my Englisch, I'm from germany .. giving my best :)

Comment: I followed your link for Compositing Graphics and found the right one for me. It is `DstOut` :) THANK YOU VERY MUCH ! This helped me a lot ! :)

Comment: Cool! :-) I fixed a typo in the optimization tip as well, used the wrong variable there. But seems you are on the right track now! :-)